# Show that the ring isomorphism $\phi :R[x]\to S[x]$ is well-defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Could someone please verify whether my answer is too simple or needs more detail or something is wrong?

> Let $\phi_{1}:R\to S$ be a ring isomorphism. Show that the ring isomorphism $\phi_{2} :R[x]\to S[x]$ defined by $\phi_{2}(a_{0}+a_{1}x+\cdots +a_{n}x^{n})=\phi_{1}(a_{0})+\phi_{1}(a_{1})x+\cdots + \phi_{1}(a_{n})x^{n}$ is well-defined.

Let $f(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+\cdots +a_{n}x^{n},g(x)=b_{0}+b_{1}x+\cdots +b_{m}x^{m}\in R[x]$. If $f(x)=g(x)$, by polynomial equality, $a_{0}=b_{0}$, ..., $a_{n}=b_{m}$. Then $n = m$ (?). Then $\phi_{2}(f)=\phi_{1}(a_{0})+\phi_{1}(a_{1})x+\cdots + \phi_{1}(a_{n})x^{n}=\phi_{1}(b_{0})+\phi_{1}(b_{1})x+\cdots + \phi_{1}(b_{m})x^{m}=\phi_{2}(g)$.

Comment: Where did you find this problem?  It's really weird to ask to check that this is "well-defined"...

Comment: Do you want to show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism ?

Comment: @EricWofsey I have to show that $\phi_{2}$ is a ring isomorphism and I thought checking that $\phi_{2}$ is well-defined is one of the steps. Do I need to check it though? The other steps for checking whether it is an isomorphism I have done already.

Comment: You only have to check that a map is well-defined if it could possibly _not_ be well-defined, in other words if it is defined in terms of some non-unique representation of elements of the domain.

Comment: I see, so by the construction of $\phi_{2}$, it is obviously well-defined?

Comment: Right, it is obvious enough that you don't even have to mention it.  As I said in my answer, if you want to be super-precise, you could specify that $a_n\neq 0$ if $n\neq 0$ when making your definition to make sure the representation you're using is unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty weird problem.  When you are asked to show something is "well-defined", that means it is defined by using representatives of some equivalence classes, and you want to show the resulting definition does not depend on the choice of representatives.  But here, there do not appear to be any such equivalence classes.  At worst, you might say that the expression $$a_{0}+a_{1}x+\cdots +a_{n}x^{n}$$ for a polynomial is not unique, since you could add extra terms to the end with coefficients $0$ (so, in the context of what you wrote, the problem is that you might have $m\neq n$).  So you would need to check that adding extra terms with coefficient $0$ to the end doesn't change the definition of $\phi_2$.  (And this is completely trivial to check, since $\phi_1(0)=0$.)  But actually, the usual approach would not be to make this definition with this ambiguity and then ask you to prove that it's well-defined, but instead to stipulate that $a_n\neq 0$ (unless $n=0$), to make the expression above unique.  In that case, there is literally nothing to check to prove that $\phi_2$ is well-defined; you don't even need to do the work that you did.

My guess would be that whoever wrote the problem actually intended to ask you to prove that this map is an isomorphism, not that that it is well-defined.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question. You're right, the question was asking to show it is an isomorphism. However, I thought I'd have to check whether the map is well-defined as one of the steps to being an isomorphism. The other steps (operation-preserving, injectivity, surjectivity) I already know. Does that mean I do not have to check this property?